# Sublime Text 2 and MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sublimetext, sublimetext2

Good day!

Can anyone share their experience how to attach MinGW-compiler to Sublime?

I found a config in the internet, but when I run compiled program popping bugs with missing files from "../MinGW/bin/".

Config:

```
{
   "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
   "path": "c:\\Program Files\\MinGW\\bin\\"
}
```

Thanks!

## **UPD**

I found answer for my question! I had to add one parameter in `cmd`. It's `"-static"`.

So, it's my `MinGW.sublime-build`, which works fine:

```
{
    "path": "c:\\Program Files\\MinGW\\bin\\",
    "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-static", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"]
}
```

Comment: I noticed something... If you put the compiled file in the directory ".. / MinGW / bin /", then everything runs fine and works. I understand, the problem is covered under the nose, but I can't solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to include the bin file in the "Path" variable on your system.

Open the start menu and type "variable" or "environment variable" (or google it) to find how to do it. You'll get in a Window with a lot of variables, find the Path (and not PATH) variable and add the path to the bin folder of MinGW.

And btw, as suggested, you should change file_base_name by file, and put file_base_name where you put file_base.

Here's the command I personally use:

`"cmd": ["C:\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe", "-Wall", "-time", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"]`

Comment: Thank you! But I found answer for my question. Read **UPD**.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using $file instead of $file_name. $file_name expands to only the name whereas $file expands to the full path.

The changed config would be

```
{
   "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],
   "path": "c:\\Program Files\\MinGW\\bin\\"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I again see error with missing files.