# Run cpp files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I must have gone through every other similar question on stack overflow as well as other tutorials trying to get sublime text 2 to run my cpp code but I have yet to get it to work.

My latest effort is using this guide here:
http://www.ishaanrawat.com/building-running-c-in-sublime-text-windows/

But it still will not work. The error I get is:

```
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "C:\MinGW\bin\cards.cpp" -o "C:\MinGW\bin/cards"]
[dir: C:\MinGW\bin]
[path: C:\MinGW\bin\]
```

Please can someone guide me through this. In my bin folder, the exe is called mingw-get.exe if that helps. I created an enviroment varialbe as the guide said named `MinGW` with value of `C:/MinGW/bin`

Comment: Isn't this question redundant with [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627977/sublime-text-2-and-mingw)?

Answer (score 4):

`g++` is probably not in your PATH environment variable.

**If you have admin privileges:**

Add path C:\MinGW\bin (if MinGW is located there) to your Windows path (right click on computer -> properties -> advanced properties -> environment variables -> PATH modify).

Check that `g++` is now recognized: launch a shell (cmd.exe) and type `g++ --version`. It should tell you something like:

> g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
>   Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Then reopen sublime text, and launch ctrl+B. The build should succeed.

**If you have NOT admin privileges:**

1. Find C++ (or C) file preferences in Sublime Install Directory (eg: C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\C++.sublime-package). This is an archive file.
2. Extract it to your user directory (eg: C:\Users\YOUR-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\C++).
3. Edit file C++.sublime-build located in this directory, and add the path to your g++ compiler, for instance:

> "path": "E:\Programs\MinGW\bin\",
>
> Save the file and restart Sublime.
>
> Compilation should work now!
>
> See [this link](http://russsaidwords.blogspot.fr/2013/01/mingw-g-not-gcc-sublime-text-2.html) for more info about it.

Comment: Ahh ok. I don't have permissions to change the system variables. Thanks for your answers though.

Comment: I have not tried it as I managed to get visual studio express installed but I'm sure it will help others. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Sublime but the error you have is pretty self-explanatory - you have no `g++` in your path.  Try typing `g++ --version` at your command prompt - if that doesn't work, you need to make sure your path is correctly set up pointing at your mingw bin directory.  Alternatively, if that does work, then there's a problem with your makefile.

Comment: Getting the error g++ is not recognised as an internal or external command... when i type `g++ --version` in cmd

Comment: Then you simply don't have g++ in your path.  Fix that first